RefreshView / RefreshEvent doesn't work when call LWC from Aura?
Since we can't override Standard button NEW with LWC , i'm calling my LWC from Aura component
The button NEW is placed on related list , on click it opens the form in new Tab (limit Salesforce) ,
LWC JS :
handleSuccess(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.handleCancel();

    }
handleCancel(event) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cancelo'));
    }

Aura HTML :
<aura:component
    implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:refreshView,force:hasSObjectName"
    access="global">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="parentRecordId" type="String" />

    <c:activityPortefeuilleStandardList oncancelo="{!c.handleCancel}" isModalOpen="true" recordId="{!v.parentRecordId}">
    </c:activityPortefeuilleStandardList>

</aura:component>

Aura JS :
handleCancel: function (component, event, helper) {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        console.log('Aura cancel');
        var url = window.location.href;
        var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    }

So , when i create new record it should return back to previous page and Refresh the standard list View , the refresh doesn't work ..  i tried to call the cancel on the LWC itself  RefreshEvent in LWC and it didn't worked too
Any idea?

If you are still facing this issue, put the complete code of lwc and aura component to get the better understanding of this problem.

that code describe what i'm facing
